# Autopaging or custom paging which is better in datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, paging, custompaging

i used datagrid control in .net platform... but now i am in big confusion .. that is ..which is better to used custom or autopaging option..

gud explaination or example is needed..

i dont know about any method.. very well.

i find on search.. but i dont find good material..

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements, or what you want achieve.

The pros of custom paging are mentioned at msdn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983953(VS.71).aspx

Hope this helps you.

Custom paging samples:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210309192630/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/082901-1.shtml

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/CustomizePagerDataGrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The deciding factor is the performance of the app.  If your data set is small, you can get away with auto paging... just keep in mind that it retrieves the entire dataset on every bind.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not big you can go ahead with datagrid paging as essentially it gets all the data of your table or query to client side and page it.

But if you are having huge data you can see this article for multiple options available

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx